# Firebase error while uploading: StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to create an app using firebase storage service. When trying to upload the image to firebase server I get `object does not exist at location`, probably meaning there is a problem which my URI.
below is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.software2.notification;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //this is the pic pdf code used in file chooser
    final static int PICK_PDF_CODE = 2342;

    //these are the views
    TextView textViewStatus;
    EditText editTextFilename;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    //the firebase objects for storage and database
    StorageReference mStorageReference;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //getting firebase objects
        mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);

        //getting the views
        textViewStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatus);
        editTextFilename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFileName);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        //attaching listeners to views
        findViewById(R.id.buttonUploadFile).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.textViewUploads).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    //this function will get the pdf from the storage
    private void getPDF() {
        //for greater than lolipop versions we need the permissions asked on runtime
        //so if the permission is not available user will go to the screen to allow storage permission
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivity(intent);
            return;
        }

        //creating an intent for file chooser
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_PDF_CODE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //when the user choses the file
        if (requestCode == PICK_PDF_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            //if a file is selected
            if (data.getData() != null) {
                //uploading the file
                uploadFile(data.getData());
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "No file chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


     private void uploadFile(Uri data) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        StorageReference sRef = mStorageReference.child(Constants.STORAGE_PATH_UPLOADS + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf");
        sRef.putFile(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        textViewStatus.setText("File Uploaded Successfully");
                        Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                        while (!uriTask.isComplete());
                        Uri uri = uriTask.getResult();
                        Upload upload = new Upload(editTextFilename.getText().toString(), uri.toString() );
                        mDatabaseReference.child(mDatabaseReference.push().getKey()).setValue(upload);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                        textViewStatus.setText((int) progress + "% Uploading...");
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonUploadFile:
                getPDF();
                break;
            case R.id.textViewUploads:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, ViewUploadsActivity.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextFileName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:hint="Enter a name for your file"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUploadFile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTextFileName"
        android:text="Upload PDF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewStatus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No file selected"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewUploads"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="View Uploads"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

when I run my application and click on upload pdf it detects storagereference exception.

```
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(UploadTask.java:339)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(UploadTask.java:308)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:229)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(UploadTask.java:477)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(UploadTask.java:276)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:224)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(UploadTask.java:339)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(UploadTask.java:308)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:229)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(UploadTask.java:477)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(UploadTask.java:276)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:224)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: do you have more than one storage bucket or you have just on storage bucket

Comment: No. there is only one storage bucket

Comment: can you tell me what type of path in your `Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS` maybe problem would there.

Comment: No. still it says object does not exist at location

Comment: public class Constants {

        public static final String STORAGE_PATH_UPLOADS = "uploads/";
        public static final String DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS = "uploads";
    }

Comment: do you know on which line this error occured!

Comment: No. it does detect the line number

Comment: `sRef.putFile(data)`. You probably should put a File there. Not a content scheme uri.

Comment: I don't think so. we inserting file in url format. i guess problem with my firebase connection

Comment: you can give a try by using `addOnCompleteListener` instead of `OnSuccessListener` and then you can get download URL by doing `sRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(...)` let me know if it works or not

Comment: yes. i tried same. but still getting error

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help.